# Flutter WebViewPlus - use css file from local html string

Tags: html, css, flutter, webview

I am using a local HTML string, in which I use the style.css from assets/html directory:

```
  final String html = """    <!DOCTYPE html>  
    <html>  
    <head>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/html/style.css">  
        </head>  
      <body>  
       <h2>Simple HTML with External CSS</h2>  
        <p class="blue">This is a blue color paragraph</p>  
        <p class="red">This is a red color paragraph</p>  
        <p class="green">This is a green color paragraph</p>  
      </body>  
    </html>  """;
```

The css file is:

```
body{
background-color:lavender;
text-align: center;
}
h2{
font-style: italic;
size: 30px;
color: #f08080;
}
p{
font-size: 20px;
}

.blue{
color: blue;
}
.red{
color: red;
}
.green{
color: green;
}
```

The code of the WebViewPlus is:

```
return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    body: WebViewPlus(
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
        controller.loadString(html);
      },
    )
  );
```

The result is just a simple text without using the style.css file. How should I reference the css file from assets folder?
What should I use for href="<LOCATION_OF_CSS>"

I modified pubspec.yaml to include the assets/html folder.

Thanks!